# Segmentation Fault when accessing second element in obj vector using pointer

Tags: c++

please take a look at this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    private:
        string contentA;

    public:
        A(){ contentA = ""; };
        A( string setContent ){ contentA = setContent; };
        virtual string printContent(){ return contentA; };
};

class B: public A
{
    private:
        string contentB;

    public:
        B( string setContent ){ contentB = setContent; };
        virtual string printContent(){ return contentB; };
};

int main()
{

    vector<A*> aPointer;
    vector<B> bVector;      

    B b1("b1");
    //store b1 obj in bVector
    bVector.push_back( b1 );
    //store the current(last) obj address to aPointer for access later
    aPointer.push_back( &bVector.back() );

//    B b2("b2");
//    bVector.push_back( b2 );
//    aPointer.push_back( &bVector.back() );

    for( vector<A*>::iterator it = aPointer.begin(); it != aPointer.end(); it++ )
    {
        cout << (*it)->printContent() << endl;
    }
}
```

aPointer will store pointer to the element of B vector.

May i ask why does it has a segmentation fault when i access the 2nd element in my B vector in the for loop?

I've hex in and it will work fine again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to remember that a `std::vector` is of variable size. When you add an element to a vector, it might have to reallocate the data, so any pointer to the vector will be invalid after such a reallocation.

What happens here is probably such a reallocation, so one pointer will be invalid and dereferencing it will be undefined behavior and in your case cause a crash.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, if thats the case, how do i access back the bVector without a pointer to the element?

Comment: @curiosity Unfortunately you simply can't store pointers (or references) to individual elements of a std::vector (or any other collection that can dynamically reallocate its data). You could use e.g. a std::list instead.

Comment: Actually you can store the pointers if you know that you are not going to perform any such operations. There are ways to ensure this doesn't happen, e.g. reserve().

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not when you're accessing the second element of `aPointer`: it's when you access the first. As you'll see, this problem is caused when `std::vector` grows/resizes and reallocates memory. When it does this, references (pointers, iterators and `&` references) are invalidated, meaning it causes undefined behavior when you access those invalidated references (the effect, in your case, is a segmentation fault).

Let us see what's really causing the problem:

```
B b1("b1");
bVector.push_back( b1 );
aPointer.push_back( &bVector.back() );

B b2("b2");
bVector.push_back( b2 );
aPointer.push_back( &bVector.back() );
```

Oooh! You are pushing back two elements, whose addresses are stored at the time they are added. The problem is in there. When you do your second `push_back`, it causes reallocation and resizing, thus invalidating references to existing elements inside `bVector`. And you have an existing element inside that vector and an already invalidated reference to it! That reference is currently the first element of `aPointer` and it points to a memory location you're not suppose to point and access.

Thus, when you do your iteration, you access the first element of `aPointer`, and thus causing a segmentation fault.

To solve your problem, don't store a vector of pointers to corresponding elements of another vector! You could just pass the whole vector around (preferably by reference, so that we'll not incur the cost of copying) and do operations directly on the elements themselves. This will surely save you an hour of headache and will result in better, shorter code.

Answer (score 1):

As both Joachim Pileborg and Mark Garcia have mentioned, it's a problem with the vector container reallocating memory.

To resolve this, you can use the `vector.reserve` method to pre-allocate memory for your vectors. While this will work for your situation here, it's just a band-aid and should not be taken as *the* way to fix this. EDIT: I want to emphasize that I've posted this only because it could be of interest. Joachim and Mark provide proper methods to address the root issue.

```
int main()
{

    vector<A*> aPointer;
    vector<B> bVector;      

    //reserve some space. There's no special meaning to choosing 16.
    aPointer.reserve(16);
    bVector.reserve(16); 

    B b1("b1");
    bVector.push_back( b1 );
    aPointer.push_back( &bVector.back() );

    B b2("b2");
    bVector.push_back( b2 );
    aPointer.push_back( &bVector.back() );

    for( vector<A*>::iterator it = aPointer.begin(); it != aPointer.end(); it++ )
    {
        cout << (*it)->printContent() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: An alternative option would be to use a collection that does not invalidate pointers and references to its elements when you grow it, like list or deque.